# How to grant APT priveleges without sudo

Tags: linux, permissions, apt

I'd like to give users on an Ubuntu system permissions to APT. However sudo is not a viable option because you can easily escalate to a root shell from APT. Any other ways to give a user APT privileges?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best way to go about this is to set up your `/etc/sudoers`.  I would first recommend creating a group to add users to that will have permission to run apt (from here on, I will assume that 'apt' is `/usr/bin/apt`).  We'll call this group the `apt_users`.

```
#groupadd apt_users
#groupmems -a <some user> -g apt_users
```

Then we will modify the `/etc/sudoers` file to give users of this group permission to run apt.  As root user, call `visudo` to open up the sudoers file.  Then add a line to the file:

```
%apt_users     localhost=/usr/bin/apt
```

Now the user that you've added to the apt_users group should have permission to run `sudo apt` without being granted any other elevated permissions, but will still be required to enter their password.